# xstream on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, xstream

I know there is a problem with xstream on Google app engine because of the security reasons. I observed few patches are applied to make it work on gae for xstream. Can any one have the version of jar or is there any alternative way to make xml to java other than JAXP in Gae ?

Comment: I'm also interested by this solution. Did you find something by yourself?

Answer (score 7):

Because of GAE's restrictions, you'll have to:

- change its default reflection provider to PureJavaReflectionProvider
- Omit some of the object converters which are automatically registered when an instance of XStream is created, most notably the AWT and Swing class converters, and the DynamicProxy converter.

I've posted an implementation built on top of XStream that makes it compatible with GAE. No patching is required. The link to the implementation is here: http://www.wappworks.com/2011/11/11/using-xstream-with-google-app-engine/

Comment: This implementation helped me out greatly.  I did however have to add an extra couple of converters which had not been registered.  In my case:

   registerConverter(new EnumConverter(), PRIORITY_NORMAL);
   registerConverter(new EnumSetConverter(mapper), PRIORITY_NORMAL);
   registerConverter(new EnumMapConverter(mapper), PRIORITY_NORMAL);

Comment: @chris-koo I tried your solution but still getting errors, can you help me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802986/xstream-and-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

There's now a jar on the attachments for this JIRA item:
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR-566

It seems to work for serialising to XML but not necessarily the reverse.

Sadly the patch doesn't seem to have been integrated into the official releases yet.